# How to make a multi-color indeterminate linear progress indicator using material design in android?

Tags: android, xml, material-design, android-progressbar, material-components-android

I want to implement a progress bar similar to this:

[image]

In material design [documentation](https://material.io/components/progress-indicators/android#linear-progress-indicators) it says I need to set `indeterminateAnimationType` to `contiguous` to achieve this and provide three colors. But how to provide three colors when the `indicatorColor` attribute accepts only 1 color ?

When I run this code it throws an exception says `Contiguous indeterminate animation must be used with 3 or more indicator colors`:

```
<com.google.android.material.progressindicator.LinearProgressIndicator
android:id="@+id/progress"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:indeterminate="true"
app:indeterminateAnimationType="contiguous"
app:hideAnimationBehavior="outward"
app:showAnimationBehavior="inward"
app:trackThickness="5dp" />
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a minimum requirement of 3 indicator colors to use the contiguous animation.

Just use the **`indicatorColor`** attribute with an array:

```
        <com.google.android.material.progressindicator.LinearProgressIndicator
            android:id="@+id/progress"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            app:indeterminateAnimationType="contiguous"
            app:indicatorColor="@array/progress_colors"
            ../>
```

with `array/progress_colors`:

```
<integer-array name="progress_colors">
    <item>@color/....</item>
    <item>@color/....</item>
    <item>@color/....</item>
</integer-array>
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah this works. I didn't know how to reference an array in XML.

Comment: @Gabriele Mariotti, Thanks for the hint. I was unable to understand the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the clear and concise answer. This works perfectly.